# C++ Cout converted string to decimal number with keeping all the decimals

Tags: c++

I got a little problem that I cannot solve easily. I am converting a string to double using stod() but it gives me a rounded decimal number (eg. 47.56164167 will give 47.5616). I need more decimals than 4. Is there another C++ function I can call that would convert my string to double without doing anything else?

Ok, it was the display method involved, not the stod() function.

Comment: how do you know that the number is rounded?

Comment: Could it be that when you output it, you have precision (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/precision/) set on the output stream? Some code example would greatly help us help you

Comment: Well, when the converted number is printed/cout, it seems to be rounded. It may be the output step, but it sometimes gives 4 decimals, sometimes 5 (and 0 is not the 5th decimal when it printed only 4 decimals).

Comment: The rounding you are talking about occurs on printing. Learn to print more significant digits and you'll see that your number was parsed fine.

Comment: Use a [decimal floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_floating_point).  Such as Boost.Multiprecision [`cpp_dec_float`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/floats/cpp_dec_float.html)

Comment: Perhaps it's the printing that rounds the number. Run some tests that don't involve printing, e.g. `assert(47.56164167 == std::stod("47.56164167"))`

Comment: Ok, thank you all for the first quick answers. I will check them out.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: do **not** use decimal floating point if you don't need it.

Comment: @n.m. If you're worried about accurate decimal representation of your numbers, then you do need it.

Comment: Alright, just switch your application from `Release` to `Debug`. Add a breakpoint to the line you want the debugger to stop. And start debugging. Then continue by stepping your application with `Next` `Next Instruction(for gdb users)`, `Step Into`, `Step Out`

Comment: The question is not bad because it can be answered with a debugger. The question is bad because it does not show exactly what the asker has done, so anyone who wants to help him is felt guessing what method he may have used to print. A question like this should include a http://sscce.org

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: you should only worry about more accurate decimal representation of your numbers **if you know** that what you have otherwise is not accurate enough. This was not demonstrated.

Comment: @n.m. I will counter your claim. Use decimal floating point, if you think you might have the slightest possibility of needing it, because not using it when you should will lead to subtle bugs in your code.  Only use binary floating point if you know for sure it will work for your purposes, and you need the performance.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Huh? Why on earth should I have *any* need to use decimal numbers, as opposed to, I don't know, duodecimal? Base 10 is not magic and the fact that most people have 10 digits on their hands is not a sufficient reason to prefer it over other bases.

Comment: @n.m. I don't know.  Maybe you're making a calculator, and you want to accept user input from humans, and you want the calculations to be accurate?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: that's a very special application which could indeed warrant using decimal numbers. Or not, depending on your requirements. There's no real scientific reason to demand exactly representable numbers, your input data is not exact anyway, or you shouldn't be using floating point with it at all. But if that's what people want, I guess I could give them that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that you set the precision on the output stream before sending it a double or float. This will ensure that the entire value is generated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
int main()
{
    std::stringstream svalue("47.56164167");
    double dvalue;

    svalue >> dvalue;
    std::cout << dvalue << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::setprecision(10) << dvalue << std::endl;
}
```

This outputs the following

> 47.5616
>   47.56164167

Keep in mind that a `double` cannot represent *all* numbers and you may see some rounding happening depending on the value you store in it.